# How to set different gravitydirection vector for different items of gravitybehavior?

Tags: ios, iphone

```
I have two UIViews.i want to set different gravitydirection vector for these two views for making **attraction**.and i am doing this by having two gravitybehavior but when i am adding these two to animator.
it's not working as **attracting** to each other.
also giving warning like :-Multiple gravity behavior per animator is undefined and may assert in the future.
Below is the code i am using to make Attractiuon effect b/w two views.
```

gravity behavior is to make the gravity animation.and animator is dynamic animator.

```
UIGravityBehavior *gravityBehavior = [[UIGravityBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[v1]];

      CGVector vector = CGVectorMake(1.0, 1.0);

    [gravityBehavior setGravityDirection:vector];


    UIGravityBehavior *gravityBehavior1 = [[UIGravityBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[v2]];
        CGVector vector1 = CGVectorMake(-1.0, -1.0);

    [gravityBehavior1 setGravityDirection:vector1];
    gravityBehavior.magnitude=1000;

       self.animator = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView:self.view];
    [self.animator addBehavior:gravityBehavior];
     [self.animator addBehavior:gravityBehavior1];
```

Please Help!
Thanks for the Help!!

Comment: define different dynamic animator and assign each gravity behavior to differenet dynamic animator